# Parallax Image Scrolling Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

So I am trying to get an image to have a parallax scrolling effect, buts its not working. Got any idea on why it isnt working?

```
$(function() {

// Cache the Window object
var $window = $(window);

// Parallax Backgrounds
// Tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641



$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            // Scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        }); // end window scroll
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0382k30q/

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What errors are you getting? What should be happening that isn't? One thing I noticed is that you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: The image in the background is supposed to scroll at a different pace and your browser to give the effect of it being at a distance. So basically, the image isn't moving.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* There isn't enough code in this post to reproduce the issue. The code in your fiddle needs to be in the question too.

Comment: It's also not clear whether not including jQuery was just a mistake in creating the fiddle or part of the original problem.

Comment: That was a mistake. It is now updated.

Comment: Here is it https://jsfiddle.net/0382k30q/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){...
```

to this:

```
$('div[data-type="background"]').each(function(){...
```

The backgrounds aren't applied to the section element. They are applied to a div element.

Also, don't forget to include JQuery/JQuery UI in your fiddles.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0382k30q/7/